# Как задать async в полученном файле из gulp-uglify?

Tags: javascript, gulp, npm, gulp-uglify

Какой параметр нужно поменять, чтобы на выходе из gulp-uglify выходил файл с асинхронной загрузкой (async) ?

Вот html-код:

```
 <!--build:js js/main.min.js -->
   <script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js "></script>
   <script src="js/levitation.js"></script>
   <script src='js/burger.js'></script>
   <script src='js/scroll.js'></script>
   <script src="js/script.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Вот gulp-сonfig:

```
gulp.task("useref", function () {
    return gulp.src("Full/*html")
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', cssnano()))
        // .pipe(gulpif('*.html', htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true})))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./Clean')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно просто добавить параметр через пробел:

```
<!--build:js js/main.min.js async -->
  <script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js "></script>
  <script src="js/levitation.js"></script>
  <script src='js/burger.js'></script>
  <script src='js/scroll.js'></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```